# Wrong ids in Bootstrap modals with components inside a dynamicform in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, bootstrap-modal, dynamicform

I have a problem trying to use a Bootstrap modal with components inside a dynamicform in Yii2.

The modal ids don't generate well for every new item (row) I create. If there are several items beforehand, at PHP execution time, the ids generate OK but at client side whenever I create a new item, the id is cloned verbatim from the first item, instead of generating a new one.

Field names and ids of components inside modals do generate OK always. But modal ids don't at client side. And I need every item to have its own modal with different ids.

Comment: Show your code, that is used to create a new item.

Comment: I just have a button with proper attributes so that the javascript from dynamicform recognize it and put prorper event listeners on it, but the new item is created by dynamicform javascript code.

Comment: Different modal ids? The approach to what you want is to have a single modal, render toggle buttons for each model (you can pass any param to them, like `data-x="{$model->x}"`) and on click, populate/manipulate whatever items you have inside the modal with the values you passed.

Comment: @Ravenous, I followed you suggestion, just forgot to thank back. So thank you!